# Нужно привязать аудио к button, чтоб при нажатии на кнопку с клавиатуры включалась и выключалась музыка

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

мне нужно привязать музыку к кнопке, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу с клавиатуры, она активировалась, при повторном нажатии, музыка отключалась

вот код:

```
       <div class="box-container">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-1">1</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-2">2</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-3">3</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-4">4</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-5">5</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-6">6</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-7">7</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-1" id="btn-8">8</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Т. е., к каждой песне из восьми на клавиатуре была привязана своя клавиша?

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли, и чтобы она включалась и так же выключалась при каждом нажатии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавляем такой скрипт:

```js
var tracks = ["1.mp3", "2.mp3", "3.mp3", "4.mp3", "5.mp3", "6.mp3", "7.mp3", "8.mp3"], // имена файлов
keycodes = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56], // коды клавиш, привязанных к ним
mycode = -1,
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button"),
audio = new Audio;
for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
 buttons[i].onclick = function(){
  var index = parseInt(this.innerHTML) - 1;
  if(index != mycode)audio.src = tracks[index];
  mycode = index;
  if(audio.paused){audio.play()}else{audio.pause()};
 }
}
document.onkeydown=function(e){
 buttons[keycodes.indexOf(e.keyCode)].click();
}
```

Это на примере клавиш с цифрами с 1 по 8.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сработало, но мне еще нужно такое сделать с буквенными клавишами: "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i", как мне привязать еще и к этим клавишам, я просто javascript пока что не знаю, спасибо большое

Comment: Для этого нужно только переписать вторую строку так: keycodes = [81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89, 85, 73],

Comment: А можете мне пожалуйста показать на примере, на всех клавишах, просто не могу разобраться, ведь мне нужно не поменять те клавиши, а добавить к ним ещё и буквенные, то есть, чтоб были "1", "2", "3,", "4", "5", "6", "7",  "8", "q", "w", "e", "r", "t", "y", "u", "i"

Comment: Используйте простую утилиту определения кода любой нажимаемой клавиши, потом эти коды через запятую запишите в массив keycodes во второй строке: **document.onkeydown = function(e){alert(e.keyCode)};**

Comment: Если хотите объединить цифры и буквы, просто напишите коды соответствующих клавиш в одном и том же массиве, как продолжение одного другим: **keycodes = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89, 85, 73],**

Comment: Я прописал эти коды а они че-то не работают

Comment: Работают только цифры

Comment: Посмотрите, вроде сделал так как вы сказали, но почему-то не работает

Comment: var tracks = ["1.mp3", "2.mp3", "3.mp3", "4.mp3", "5.mp3", "6.mp3", "7.mp3", "8.mp3", "9.mp3", "10.mp3", "11.mp3", "12.mp3", "13.mp3", "14.mp3"], // имена файлов
keycodes = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 81, 87, 69, 82, 84, 89], // коды клавиш, привязанных к ним

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83001/discussion-between--and-).

Comment: Да, давайте в чате, только я не знаю, где там писать

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83001/discussion-between--and-

Comment: Доведите количество <button>...</button> и количество треков до 14. Тогда будет соответствие.